# .htaccess help - how to hide folder in index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

i have an index of files,
the home page is just index of all the files & folders...
and every file&folder is there.

is there any way to hide specific folder?
the folders are like that:

-www
--xxxfolder (TO SHOW)
--yyyfolder (TO HIDE)
--ZZZfolder (TO HIDE)
--TTTfolder (TO SHOW)
--GGGfile (TO SHOW)
-- and so on.....

how i'm hiding YYY&ZZZ and show everything else?

Comment: Please post more details, this is not enough information to understand the problem, post code if possible.  For example, I'm guessing the goal is to accomplish this via .htaccess, post your current .htaccess file and what you have tried to help us understand your problem.

Comment: i am seeing the current files that on my server via the regular index...
no site, no pages at all, no index.html etc...
just index of files from the root....
there i can see all my files & folder on the server.
i want to hide 2 folders from that index.